# How to pass data values between pages

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm getting and showing data from database. I was created button which one redirects to another page and fill form data. Button redirects to another this application page and sets items (names, values). If I set static value - it's works. But how I can pass data from columns (`MAX_PHOTOS`, `MAX_PHOTO_SIZE`) using Page Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a link, you have options.
http://prntscr.com/t70l76

You type in the Page number, and then below that you set items. You can just click the buttons next to the lines and it shows you the items on the target page and the items on the source page, you select those and thats that.

If you are writting them in yourself, then you can do `&P1_ITEM.` Dont forget the `.` at the end. This also works for other uses where you need to reference page items. But know that those values must be submitted in order for them to be used.

Comment: I have created hidden items https://prnt.sc/t8a1yn, https://prnt.sc/t8a28o and use https://prnt.sc/t8a1as. If I don't create hidden items, designer not see them when i chooseing in "Set Items" section. How I can submit values?

Comment: @ES. From what i can see these items are set from the DB directly, so they are already submited. What usually happens and why I told you to submit them is that sometimes people have these items as just text fields, then they put in some value and are then perplexed why this new value is not transfered to the new page. Thing is when you manually alter a value that value needs to be submitted(saved) sometimes that is achieved by pressing Enter after changing the value. But sometimes you must run a dynamic action with the action being PLSQL code, the code can just be NULL, but you submit items.

Comment: sorry, but I still can't understand how to pass values from DB to another page. I solve this problem another way, but I don't know it good or not. I create items with queries https://prnt.sc/t8blpj and pass this elements values to another page.

Comment: If I set type "Database Column" it's still not working ( https://prnt.sc/t8bsuz )

Comment: @ES. I think perhaps you arent setting the value correctly. Check the session state(if you open the page from the developer there is a tab on the bottom middle of the screen where one of the options is Session) there you can see all the values for items that are submitted and have been saved.
However I suspect that what is the problem for you is that you arent actually fetching those values. Source Database Column needs an Automatic Row Fetch on the page for it to work. Thats a process that runs during Pre-rendering that fetches the line in the DB and the items then take from there.

Comment: @ES. checked some more and Automatic Row Fetch seems to have been deprecated as of 19.1. So if you are on a new version of APEX you will need to use a different process. More information is availible here: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/forms-in-apex-191-more-power%2c-more-flexibility